# Is this answer an answer or comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, review

I was just presented with [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/644075/186134) as a Late Answers review. Screenshot in case it is removed:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

It this a valid answer, or is it someone commenting? They're offering a solution (format first) but seem to be giving their own progress.

What should I have done with this? I skipped it.

Comment: Probably someone posting like it is a forum...

Comment: I'd treat is as comment.

Comment: It's a comment.